# How the data on SD are encrypted in 4.0?

Tags: sd-card, encryption

I've got phone with android 4.0, and, for sync with Exchange, I encrypted SD card using android's built-in encryption. However, the phone starts telling me that the card is damaged and needs formatting.

I just want to take the data (photos) out before formatting, I've got the phone, and remember my PIN. (I can also do the bitwise copy of the card). How are the data encrypted? What do I need for decrypting? I assume that the card is encrypted whole, not only files on the filesystem, so when I decrypt it I may be able to dig the data out.

Thanks

Comment: You probably need one more thing (the encryption key which is e.g. located below /efs on Samsung). Here's some more info with a python script to handle it (on the phone alas): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=25635462&postcount=54